# Problem connecting power bi and mongoDB remote

Tags: mongodb, odbc, powerbi-desktop, mongosqld

I am trying connect to remote mongodb, alredy installed:

1. MongoDB
2. Mongo Tools
3. MongoODBC
4. Mongo Connector BI

i am trying run the mongosqld(connector BI) with the setup of remote but always have this output:

```
log output directed to C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Connector for BI\2.14\logs\mongosqld.log
2022-04-07T10:56:11.928-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] mongosqld starting: version=v2.14.4 pid=12408 host=CPX-KPKS8VEZ1B3
2022-04-07T10:56:11.928-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] git version: df0cf0b57e9aac0ab6d545eee0d4451d11d0c6e9
2022-04-07T10:56:11.928-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.0.2n-fips  7 Dec 2017 (built with OpenSSL 1.0.2s  28 May 2019)
2022-04-07T10:56:11.928-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] options: {config: "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Connector for BI\\2.14\\example-mongosqld-config.yml", systemLog: {path: "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Connector for BI\\2.14\\logs\\mongosqld.log", verbosity: 2}, schema: {stored: {mode: "custom", source: "mongosqld_data", name: "mySchema"}}, net: {bindIp: [10.40.20.9], port: 27030}, mongodb: {net: {uri: "mongodb://10.40.20.9:27030", auth: {source: "admin"}}}}
2022-04-07T10:56:11.928-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for mongosqld.
2022-04-07T10:56:11.928-0500 I CONTROL    [initandlisten]
error populating listeners: listen tcp 10.40.20.9:27030: bind: The requested address is not valid in its context.
```

this is my setup for the mongosqld

```
systemLog:
  logAppend: false
  path: "/var/log/mongosqld/mongosqld.log"
  verbosity: 2

security:
  enabled: true

mongodb:
  net:
    uri: "10.40.20.9:27030"
    auth:
      username: "GONZJIM1"
      password: "Colombia_2021"

net:
  bindIp: 10.40.20.9
  port: 27030
  ssl:
    mode: "disabled"
systemLog:  
  path: 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Connector for BI\2.14\logs\mongosqld.log'
  quiet: false  
  verbosity: 2
  logRotate: "rename" 

processManagement:
  service:
    name: mongosqld
    displayName: mongosqld
    description: "BI Connector SQL proxy server"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are using the same IP Address and Port Number in the bindIP and the mongodb IP.  Since the database is already using that IP Address and Port Number, just change the Port Number in the bindIP area to 27031 and see if it is successful.